# Ubuntu under Windows 10 Linux Subsystem

Tags: dpkg, windows-10

Everybody, I am new to Ubuntu. And I try to install Ubuntu 18.04 under windows Linux subsystem.

In one step I am going to install `libdvd-pkg`, but get an error as shown below:

```
sudo apt-get install libdvd-pkg
[sudo] password for xyz:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libdvd-pkg is already the newest version (1.4.2-1-1).
libdvd-pkg set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
7 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up libdvd-pkg (1.4.2-1-1) ...
libdvd-pkg: Checking orig.tar integrity...
/usr/src/libdvd-pkg/libdvdcss_1.4.2.orig.tar.bz2: OK
libdvd-pkg: Unpacking and configuring...
libdvd-pkg: Building the package... (it may take a while)
libdvd-pkg: Build log will be saved to /usr/src/libdvd-pkg/libdvdcss2_1.4.2-1~local_amd64.build
failed to set securebits to 024/0x14
dpkg: error processing package libdvd-pkg (--configure):
 installed libdvd-pkg package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up ruby-molinillo (0.6.4-1) ...
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 unable to install updated status of 'ruby-molinillo': No such file or directory
libdvd-pkg: Checking orig.tar integrity...
/usr/src/libdvd-pkg/libdvdcss_1.4.2.orig.tar.bz2: OK
libdvd-pkg: Unpacking and configuring...
libdvd-pkg: Building the package... (it may take a while)
libdvd-pkg: Build log will be saved to /usr/src/libdvd-pkg/libdvdcss2_1.4.2-1~local_amd64.build
failed to set securebits to 024/0x14
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Is there anybody, who can explain this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!!! ,you have `7 not fully installed or removed.` ,try to run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. and run update/upgrade your apt.

Comment: I am having the same problem and `sudo dpkg --configure -a` does not work.

Comment: @rabejens What happens when you try to run `dpkg --configure -a`? Did you ever solve this?

Comment: It just tries to reconfigure `libdvd-pkg` and the same error happens.

Comment: Probably this answer will help you: https://askubuntu.com/a/1174098/566421

Comment: Has anyone found a fix for this? I'm experiencing the same problem and can't find any solution on the internet.

Comment: @ChaosFreak If you still looking for a solution, you may try my suggestion below. Also if you fixed it another way, may be share it which may help other.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to find out why `capsh` is failing to set `securebits`, but no success. Anyway, that error is same when `capsh` is run by a non superuser.

As workaround you can:

1. Modify that script to use `bash` instead in `/usr/lib/libdvd-pkg/b-i_libdvdcss.sh` which is called by `postinst`. Change this line:

   ```
   CAPSH="$(which capsh) --secbits=0x14 --drop=cap_dac_read_search,cap_fsetid,cap_kill,cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_linux_immutable,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_broadcast,cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw,cap_ipc_lock,cap_ipc_owner,cap_sys_module,cap_sys_rawio,cap_sys_chroot,cap_sys_ptrace,cap_sys_pacct,cap_sys_admin,cap_sys_boot,cap_sys_nice,cap_sys_resource,cap_sys_time,cap_sys_tty_config,cap_mknod,cap_lease,cap_audit_write,cap_audit_control,cap_setfcap,cap_mac_override,cap_mac_admin,cap_syslog-ep --print --" || CAPSH=/bin/bash
   ```

   to:

   ```
   CAPSH=/bin/bash
   ```
2. Then fix APT

   ```
   sudo apt install -f
   ```

I read also it work fine with WSL2 (which a VM). Bug Report: [github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4278](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4278)