# How can install developer tools on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: software-installation

I am an absolute beginner in Ubuntu and I am  trying to install developer tools. Can someone guide me I have tried the following:[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't provide pictures of text; I want to copy details from your screen to look up info & answer but cannot copy/paste from a picture.  Use text please

Comment: Hello, Muhammad Maqsoodur Rehman, did you succeed with this issue?

Comment: @pa4080 Yes.The problem is solved now. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the repositories before install or upgrade something. So probably `sudo apt update && sudo apt install --fix-missing` will fix your problem, after that try to install the desired package again.